# Twitter Bootstrap Popover - IE7 delay

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, internet-explorer-7, popover

I have built a map with a Bootstrap Popover on it.

When I hover over my left-menu in **IE7** Only. The popover box appears at roughly 10%, Then after a delay of 4 or 5 seconds. It loads.

Has anyone come across any issues with Popover and IE7?

My JS is setup as follows :

```
    $('.hover_over').popover(
        {   html:true,
            animation:true,
            delay: 0
        }
)
```

I also have some conditional IE7 code setup...

```
<!--[if IE 7]>
<style type="text/css">
    .popover {
        *max-width:70% !important;
    }
    .popover-title {
        height: auto !important;
        padding-bottom: 4px !important;
    }
    .tooltip_main {
        margin-top: 5px !important;
    }
</style>
<![endif]-->
```

Any help appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Why do you make your site compatible for IE7... IE6 and 7 are nearly dead.

Comment: Thanks for your reponse! The reason being this is for a large business supplier in my area, Unfortunatley some of there users will appear on IE7. Hope this is a useful answer..

Comment: What kind of business is that? IE7 serious? I don't think IE7 supports what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: I agree with your point and the stats suggest best not to worry too much about it. But as I say a lot of these businesses unfortunatley will be in that 1% that used IE7 in May 2013 :-(

Comment: TBS doesn't work that great in IE7. Does this feature work in IE7 on the TBS site? If so, then the issue is in your implementation. Also, consider Chrome Frame.

Comment: Cheers for your reply Scott. Totally agree IE7 is a pain